# How to preload image for a NetworkImageView of Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm dynamically generate `NetworkImageView` for an Internet image, and it starts to fetch real file when the view is created.

Is there a way to force Volley library to cache files of some url, before I really create the view? Or do I need to use `ImageRequest` and handle the cached files by myself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use ImageLoader where you can put a string url and I want to believe it caches it, but there is also a bitmap listener (to let you know when it is done loading), so I'm not sure if this can just be added to the network call to your server